# Blender 2.8 on an Old PC notebook

Tags: startup-file

My question is,I am running a HP Pavilion dv7 windows 7 64 bit  AMD A-6 34000 H D graphics 1.40 GHz can I  download and create with Blender 2.8 
Thanks
Ace 59

Comment: You can always download and create with blender, the question is how much you will be able to handle. For example, I use blender on a laptop, and it runs fine, but it will run really slowly if I have too many vertices in any scene, whereas on my pc i can have much more complex ones.

So it really depends what you want to do. If you are looking to create simpler stuff, you should be fine.

Comment: You likely won't be able to run Blender 2.8, since your hardware doesn't seem to meet the minimum requirements (https://www.blender.org/download/requirements/). There is no harm in trying it anyway, but don't be surprised if it doesn't work properly.